# In general, can't the combine process be parallelized?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Combine process always runs on a single machine.

Is it difficult to parallelize this process as a principle of computing?

The attached figure shows the CPUusage of Dataflow, and the Combine process is running on only one machine on the right side of the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Combine](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) operation is parallelized across multiple workers via an optimization called "combiner lifting." Say, for example, one is taking a sum has three workers and the data is distributed as follows

Worker 1: `("A", 1)`, `("A", 2)`, and `("B", 100)`

Worker 2: `("A", 3)`, `("B", 200)`, and `("B", 300)`

Worker 3: `("A", 4)` and `("A", 5)`

These workers will do pre-combining and emit partial sums per key, specifically

Worker 1: `("A", 3)` and `("B", 100)`

Worker 2: `("A", 3)` and `("B", 500)`

Worker 3: `("A", 9)`

which then get shuffled to workers according to their key for a final combine

Worker 1: `("A", 3)`, `("A", 3)`, and `("A", 9)` -> `("A", 15)`

Worker 2: `("B", 100)` and `("B", 500)` -> `("B", 600)`

Worker 3: other keys

If there are not very many keys (e.g. a global combine which has exactly one key) and the combining operation is expensive (e.g. grows as the number of values are added) and there are many upstream workers this can result in limited parallelism of the final combine. Beam's combining operations have a `with_hot_keys` option that can help in this case by introducing intermediate keys to do an intermediate level of combining before the final combine.

It's also possible that other operations that get fused into the same stage running this combine are expensive. A [Reshuffle](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/other/reshuffle/) can be used to redistribute work if parallelism is possible after such a constrained stage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

That Combinator is a custom combinator, based on Combine.CombineFn, and has no keys.

It looks like this.


public class FooCombinator 
extends Combine.CombineFn<
List<CustomObject>, 
CustomAccumratoer,
 List<List<CustomObject>>
 >  implements Serializable{
, , , , , 



This is probably the reason why HotKey is created, but Reshuffle is Deprecated and I'm in trouble.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.html

Comment: Don't worry about Reshuffle being depreciated, it's only depreciated in the context of using it to force stable inputs. This use is fine.

Comment: Given that your CombineFn produces `List<CustomObject>` I wonder if it gets more expensive the more inputs it is aggregating over, which could also explain why the final combine is taking so long.